Cox Hazard Ratio (multivariate) when one co-variate group has no event
I am looking at running a multivariate Cox-PH model.
I have the following binary categorical variables: X, Y and Z.
Thus the co-variate groups are X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Z1, and Z2.
The problem is that X2 has no events, and so on univariate Cox-PH I get a abnormally high HR with extremely wide CIs and a non-significant P value (when its clear there is a difference on log-rank KM curve analysis). I know this is an inherent issue when there is no event for Cox-PH models.
However, I need to run a multivariate Cox-PH model that includes the X co-variate. Naturally this also gives abnormal results. Is there any way around this?

How can in be "clear that there is a difference on log rank KM curve analysis" when there are no events? There are no events for KM analysis either, so there will be nothing to analyze.  Also, the HR, as far as I can tell, should be 0 or infinite (or else give an error).

As for what you can do; I think the options are 1) Ignore X2 or 2) Get more data (but I am not 100% sure there's no other option).
